# User domain in Windows authentification in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, controllers, asp.net-mvc-controller

I want to authorize access to my Web ASP.NET MVC application only by users in MyDOMAIN (MyDOMAIN\MyUSER), and other users who don't belong to this DOMAIN can not authenticate. How to proceed?

Comment: The easiest way would be to just add those access rules to your web server. Your network admin should be able to help you with that. No need to actually write this in code.

Comment: one solution is to give the applicationpool user strict access to only one domain.Then the IIS authentication will just check in that domain

Comment: What I wanted to do is create a HomeController.cs controller with [Authorize (Users = "MyDOMAIN\\ * ")], but I do not know what to replace * in order to take all users.